# Session is null on first request

Tags: spring-session

I'm using spring-session and I really like it. However I think I'm missing something. In my application the flow goes like this:
1) User requests `HomepageController` and that controller tries to put an attribute in the request:

```
    HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();

    final String sessionIds = sessionStrategy.getRequestedSessionId(request);

    if (sessionIds != null) {
        final ExpiringSession session = sessionRepository.getSession(sessionIds);
        if (session != null) {
            session.setAttribute("attr", "value");
            sessionRepository.save(session);
            model.addAttribute("session", session);
        }
    }
```

As you can see it will try to get the sessionID from the request-cookie, and if there's a session with that ID in the repository than use it (add attribute). This is perfect, but only after the **second** request. Why? Because if I restart the server than the cookie is left with the old value, and then the first request will not find the session in the repository. After the response is committed though the cookie will be updated, so the **second** request will be correct.
And here's the question: what is wrong with my logic and how should one develop the application in order to support the first request too?

BTW, here's a sample application that demonstrates the problem:

https://github.com/paranoiabla/spring-session-issue

Comment: why so complex? you can just obtain the session and use it. The whole idea is that it is as transparant as possible an you should just use the `HttpSession` and not your complex logic.

Comment: Because, again, I'm operating with the session near the db-layer (I have a `SessionService` which operates with the `SessionRepository`) and it looks ugly to operate with the `HttpServletSession` near the db-layer - it looks better when you operate with the `Session`  interface.

Comment: IMHO you shouldn't. You state this code is in a controller and that is web related. You should imho only be operating with the `HttpSession` and put stuff in there, the session will be stored for you by the framework. Looks like you are trying to work your way around Spring Session instead of embracing it. I would even dare to say that your controller is to complex.

Answer (score 2):

If you are wanting to obtain the session, you should not use requested session id. The requested session id is just that...what the browser requests. Some problems with using requested session (some of which you already outlined):

- If you clear all your cookies and make a request, then no session is requested by the browser.
- As you pointed out if the data store is restarted and is not persistent, then the requested session id is invalid
- If the session expires, then the requested session will be invalid

Instead, you should use the session id:

```
final String sessionIds = request.getSession().getId();
```

This will use the requested session id if it is valid, otherwise it will create a new session and ensure the session is written to the response (i.e. included in the response as a cookie).

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for me.The worklflow goes like this:To get the `sessionId` i do `request.getSession().getId()` calls `SessionRepositoryFilter` which calls `RedisOperationsSessionRepository` which creates the session but does NOT save it in Redis!!!.. Now I have the `sessionId`and if I call `sessionRepository.getSession(sessionId);` the repository returns `null` so all my logic throws exceptions. Then the response is commited and at some point the session is saved in redis and my SECOND request will succeed (i get session id which and I find session with that id in redis repo)

Answer (score 0):

I would say your approach is wrong, your controller does to much and you should be just using the `HttpSession` for which Spring Session provides support. You shouldn't also be putting the session in the `model` imho as you should be just accessing the `HttpSession`. Your application shouldn't know about Spring Session.

Your controller should look like this

```
@Controller
public class HomepageController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(HttpSession session) {
        session.setAttribute("attr", "value");
        return "homepage";
    }
}
```

if you don't want to force session creation inject the `HttpServletRequest` and do `getSession(false)` instead of injecting the `HttpSession`.

Everything else (storing the session after request handling etc.) will be handled transparently by Spring Session.